# UIDatePicker wrong time position when set locale

Tags: swift, locale, uidatepicker, nslocale

I have a `UIDatePicker`, that shows date and time `UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime`, when I present the picker while the language is Arabic, the picker is normally presented with hours on the left and minutes on the right with no issues as the below photo:

[image]

But if I change the language from English to Arabic, the picker switches the hours with the minutes as below:

[image]

I set the `locale` based on user selected language as:

```
if CURRENT_LANGUAGE_IS_ARABIC == true{
 pickerDate.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "ar") as Locale

}else{
 pickerDate.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "en") as Locale
}
```

**EDIT**: Also when changing from Arabic to English the picker is showing the hours on the wrong place:

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you add `semanticContentAttribute`

```
  pickerDate.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "ar") as Locale
  self.pickerDate.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```